# Android - Playing mp3 from RandomAccessFile (byte[])

Tags: android, mp3, media-player

I have my mp3 in byte[] (read from RandomAccessFile ):

```
RandomAccessFile raf=new RandomAccessFile("sdcard\myfile.mf", "r" );;
byte[] data = new byte[10000];
raf.read(data, 300, 10300);
```

and I would like to play it on my device, How can I do it?
Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you can't. But instead of reading it from the file, you can pass the FileDescriptor to the player. This will play the mp3 that starts at byte position 300 and is 10000 bytes long:

```
RandomAccessFile raf=new RandomAccessFile("sdcard\myfile.mf", "r" );
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(raf.getFD(), 300, 10000);
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

I think you also have a bug in the read call, because this would read 10300 bytes from the beginning of the file and put it to data starting from 300. Meaning: in data you'll have 300 bytes unset (garbage), then the first 9700 bytes of your file (the rest doesn't fit to the buffer)